# .NET Framework 3.5 location

Tags: windows-10

After installing .NET 3.5 Framework from "Turn Windows features on or off"

[image]

added the picture to show you what i mean. if you make that item (.Net Framework 3.5) checked, it will download and install an update, where will it be saved after downloading and installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the installer file for copying to another platform (well, perhaps it is stored in SoftwareDistribution where other Windows updates are but it may be stored in Temp as well). The installed libraries straddle many folders in both Windows and Program Files.